# FFTW3 backward doesn't work for me

Tags: c, fftw

first I apologize for my bad english...

So here is my problem. I'm testing out the FFTW3 library, with a simple input signal, a continious one. Then I compute the FFT and get the good result : just a signal on frequency 0, everything else is at 0.

Then I would like to get my input back with the backward FFT, but it doesn't work. Here is my code :

```
fftw_complex* imgIn;
fftw_complex* imgIn2;
fftw_complex* imgOut;
fftw_plan plan;

int taille = 100;
int i;

 //Allocation des entrées et sorties
imgIn = fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*taille);
imgIn2 = fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*taille);
imgOut = fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*taille);

//Remplissage des données d'entrées pour le calcul de la FFT
for(i = 0 ; i < taille ; i++){
    imgIn[i][0] = 1.0;
    imgIn[i][1] = 0.0;
}

//Plan d'execution
plan = fftw_plan_dft_2d(taille/10, taille/10, imgIn, imgOut, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

//Execute la FFT
fftw_execute(plan);

//Inverse
plan = fftw_plan_dft_2d(taille/10, taille/10, imgOut, imgIn2, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

for(i = 0 ; i < taille ; i++){
    printf("%d : %g\n%d : %g\n", i, imgIn2[i][0], i, imgIn2[i][1]);
}
```

As you can see, I just try to perform a normal FFT, then to reverse it. The problem is that my output imgIn2 is just full of 0, instead of 1 and 0...

So what's wrong with my code ?

Thank you :)

Comment: You haven't executed the second plan?

Comment: Also note that in FFTW, doing forward followed by reverse will usually leave you with a scaled result, as some of the normalization is left out and may need to be done as a post-transform step. The FFTW documentation explains that in more depth...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: If you do not post that as an answer, I will post it to “steal” your reputation and teach you a lesson. :-)

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Feel free!  I've voted to close this as "too localized"...

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not execute the second plan.